# How to run this c program in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I just saw a file about copying a file online but I dont know how to run it, I tried "gcc -o a a.c" to create a program, then when I typed "./a" it says "usage: ./a source destination" as error. What should I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE      4096

#define COPYMODE        0644

void oops(char *, char *);

void copy_file(char *, char *);

void copy(char *, char *);

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {

if (ac != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s source destination\n", *av);
    exit(1);
}

copy(av[1], av[2]);
return 0;
}

void oops(char *s1, char *s2) {
fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s ", s1);
perror(s2);
exit(1);
}

void copy_file(char *file1, char *file2) 

{
int     in_fd, out_fd, n_chars;
char    buf[BUFFERSIZE];
struct stat in_stat, out_stat;
```

Check if two files are existed

```
if (stat(file1, &in_stat) == 0 && stat(file2, &out_stat) == 0) 
{
    //Check if two files are same
    if (in_stat.st_ino == out_stat.st_ino) 
    {
        //if same, do nothing
        return;
    }
}

if ( (in_fd=open(file1, O_RDONLY)) == -1 )
    oops("Cannot open ", file1);

if ( (out_fd=creat( file2, COPYMODE)) == -1 )
    oops( "Cannot creat", file2);


while ( (n_chars = read(in_fd , buf, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0 )
    if ( write( out_fd, buf, n_chars ) != n_chars )
        oops("Write error to ", file2);
if ( n_chars == -1 )
    oops("Read error from ", file1);


if ( close(in_fd) == -1 || close(out_fd) == -1 )
    oops("Error closing files","");

if (chmod(file2, in_stat.st_mode) != 0) {
    oops("Error change file mode", "");
}
}

void copy(char *file1, char *file2) 
{
struct stat in_stat, out_stat;
struct dirent *direntp;
DIR *dir_ptr;

if (stat(file1, &in_stat) != 0) 
{
    oops("File not exist", "");
}

if (S_ISDIR(in_stat.st_mode)) 
{
    if (stat(file2, &out_stat) != 0) 
    {
        if (mkdir(file2, in_stat.st_mode) != 0) 
        {
            oops("Failed to create directory", "");
        }
    }

    if ((dir_ptr = opendir(file1)) == NULL) 
    {
        oops("Failed to open directory", "");
    } else {

        while ((direntp = readdir(dir_ptr)) != NULL) 
        {
            if (strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".") && strcmp(direntp->d_name, "..")) 
            {
                char *new_file1 = (char *)malloc(strlen(file1)+strlen(direntp->d_name)+2);
                strcpy(new_file1, file1);
                strcat(new_file1, "/");
                strcat(new_file1, direntp->d_name);

                char *new_file2 = (char *)malloc(strlen(file2)+strlen(direntp->d_name)+2);
                strcpy(new_file2, file2);
                strcat(new_file2, "/");
                strcat(new_file2, direntp->d_name);

                copy(new_file1, new_file2);
                free(new_file1);
                free(new_file2);
            }
        }
        closedir(dir_ptr);
    }
}else {
    copy_file(file1, file2);
}
}
```

I also tried to add pathname after "./a" but still not working
Sorry that I am pretty new to c language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the first few lines of `main`.

```
int main(int ac, char *av[]) {

if (ac != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s source destination\n", *av);
    exit(1);
}
```

The first argument to `main`, `ac`, is the number of arguments. You have code that prints an error message when `ac` is not equal to exactly three, and then it exits.

When you use

```
./a
```

The number of arguments to the program is 1, just the program itself.

It appears that your program expects a source file and a destination file to work correctly. You need to provide them in the command line.

```
./a file-1 file-2
```

where `file-1` is the source file and `file-2` is the destination file.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation!

Comment: @Helloitsme, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your code wants to take 2 arguments after the “.\a” which are 2 textfile path. After adding this arguments, you can run your code without error messages.

Usage:

“.\a -filepath1 -filepath2”